# Centos 8 e podman network

Tags: networking, podman, centos8

i'm tryng to use podman in Centos 8. After installing podman with command dnf install podman i have started my first container with success.

Now i want to create a network like in old docker environment with command podman network create but obtain:

Command "network" not found.
See `podman --help`.

Comment: Ok thanks my version is 1.0.5 but i cant find a method to install last version in centos 8 with rpm.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely running an old version then, the network commands have been added in [Podman 1.6.0](https://github.com/containers/libpod/releases/tag/v1.6.0):

> The `podman network create`, `podman network rm`, `podman network inspect`, and `podman network ls` commands have been added to manage CNI networks used by Podman

You can verify which version you are running with `podman --version`.

Answer (score 0):

All networks commands are available current Podman version. 
To create network `podman network create network_name` 
Show all available network `podman network ls` 
Show network details `podman network inspect network_name`
To remove network `podman network rm network_name`